# Executing cmp from bash script - "No such file or directory" on existing files

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to read through a directory and identify any files which may be duplicates in their contents.

A simplified version of this:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'

for FILEA in $(find "$1" -type f -print)
do
    echo "$FILEA"
    for FILEB in $(find "$1" -type f -print)
    do
        echo cmp \"${FILEA}\" \"${FILEB}\"
        cmp \"${FILEA}\" \"${FILEB}\"
    done
done
```

However, each instance of `cmp` complains `No such file or directory`.

If I grab the echo'd version of the cmp command, it executes exactly as expected.

Why can't cmp see the files when executed in the script context?

Comment: why do you comment the quotes for the the `cmp` command?

Comment: [Bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: Also very inefficient as you'd end up doing `cmp b a` after doing `cmp a b` (not to mention `cmp a a`). You could try your luck instead with something like `fdupes` that also compares file sizes first (files of different size can't be identical anymore).

Comment: Why do you add literal double quotes to the filenames when calling `cmp`? You may want to look into `fdupes`.

Answer (score 4):

Your main issue is that you add literal double quotes to the filenames when using `cmp` (and the filenames themselves are actually unquoted).  This is why the files can't be found (they don't have the quotes in their names).  You also loop over the output of `find`, [which is not ideal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697).

If you *really* don't want to use [`fdupes`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fdupes), you could do the following to try to make your approach a bit more efficient (speed-wise):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# enable the "**" globbing pattern,
# remove non-matched patterns rather than keeping them unexpanded, and
# allow the matching of hidden names:
shopt -s globstar nullglob dotglob

pathnames=("${1:-.}"/**)  # all pathnames beneath "$1" (or beneath "." if "$1" is empty)

# loop over the indexes of the list of pathnames
for i in "${!pathnames[@]}"; do
    this=${pathnames[i]}  # the current pathname

    # skip this if it's not a regular file (or a symbolic link to one)
    [[ ! -f "$this" ]] && continue

    # loop over the remainder of the list
    for that in "${pathnames[@]:i+1}"; do

        # skip that if it's not a regular file (or a symbolic link to one)
        [[ ! -f "$that" ]] && continue

        # compare and print if equal
        if [[ "$this" -ef "$that" ]] || cmp -s "$this" "$that"; then
            printf '"%s" and "%s" contains the same thing\n' "$this" "$that"
        fi
    done
done
```

This avoids walking the whole directory structure once for each file (which you do in your inner loop), and also avoids comparing pairs more than once.  It is still *very* slow as it needs to run `cmp` on each combination of files in the whole directory hierarchy.

Instead, you may want to try a simpler approach:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

tmpfile=$(mktemp)

find "${1:-.}" -type f -exec md5sum {} + | sort -o "$tmpfile"
awk 'FNR == NR && seen[$1]++ { next } seen[$1] > 1' "$tmpfile" "$tmpfile"

rm -f "$tmpfile"
```

This calculates the MD5 checksum for all files, sorts that list and saves it to a temporary file.  `awk` is then used to extract the `md5sum` output for all files that are duplicated.

The output will look something like

```
$ bash ~/script.sh
01b1688f97f94776baae85d77b06048b  ./QA/StackExchange/.git/hooks/pre-commit.sample
01b1688f97f94776baae85d77b06048b  ./Repositories/password-store.git/hooks/pre-commit.sample
036208b4a1ab4a235d75c181e685e5a3  ./QA/StackExchange/.git/info/exclude
036208b4a1ab4a235d75c181e685e5a3  ./Repositories/password-store.git/info/exclude
054f9ffb8bfe04a599751cc757226dda  ./QA/StackExchange/.git/hooks/pre-applypatch.sample
054f9ffb8bfe04a599751cc757226dda  ./Repositories/password-store.git/hooks/pre-applypatch.sample
2b7ea5cee3c49ff53d41e00785eb974c  ./QA/StackExchange/.git/hooks/post-update.sample
2b7ea5cee3c49ff53d41e00785eb974c  ./Repositories/password-store.git/hooks/post-update.sample
3c5989301dd4b949dfa1f43738a22819  ./QA/StackExchange/.git/hooks/pre-push.sample
3c5989301dd4b949dfa1f43738a22819  ./Repositories/password-store.git/hooks/pre-push.sample
```

In the output above, there happens to be a number of duplicated *pairs* of files.

If you have filenames that contain embedded newlines, `md5sum` will output a line prefixed with a `\` character:

```
$ touch $'hello\nworld'
$ md5sum *
\d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  hello\nworld
```

To be able to cope with this properly (by removing the backslash at the start of the line), you may want to modify the first pipeline in the script into

```sh
find "${1:-.}" -type f -exec md5sum {} + | sed 's/^\\//' | sort -o "$tmpfile"
```